# Finding clock cycle time for a pipeline prooceesor

Tags: computer-science, cpu-architecture

[image: pipeline processor]

[image: table of values]

hello,I was given the pipeline processor in the first line with information about its values in the second link.

I was asked what will be the clock cycle time of the processor.
I know it will be the max value of one of the 5 stages but no idea how to calculate it. Would appreciate help and guidance in how I can get from what to Have to what I need.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) requires some attempt.

Comment: Looks like one possible critical path is the forwarding loop from EX output back to EX input the next cycle; that might be as high as Mux + ALU + Forwarding = 18ns if I'm reading the diagram correctly.